# responsive Dropdown menu - the hidden li can not be click

Tags: html, css

I have this dropdown menu and after adding the ID tag and nav tag i am not able to hover over the drop down as they disappear as soon as i try to hover over them

please see the code here
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Cybersix/1000s8y0/)

```
<div class="container">
    <nav id="navigation">
        <label for="show-menu" class="show-menu">Menu</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="show-menu" role="button">
        <ul id="menu">
            <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">SERMONS <span>&#x25BC</span></a>
                <ul class="hidden">
                    <li><a href="#">Who We Are</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">What We Do</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">EVENTS <span>&#x25BC</span></a>
                <ul class="hidden">
                    <li><a href="#">Photography</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Web & User Interface Design</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Illustration</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">CONNECT<span>&#x25BC</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#">STAFF<span>&#x25BC</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">LOCATIONS<span>&#x25BC</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#">OTHERS<span>&#x25BC</span></a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: your jsfiddle didn't open..

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Cybersix/1000s8y0/

Comment: Corrected this http://jsfiddle.net/Cybersix/1000s8y0/ - Edit needs approval

Comment: please copy paste this if not clickable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple you just need to add this block of code to your css

```
#navigation li:hover ul
{
    display:block;
}
```

it will work fine, i have just did the change here, just added this block of code and its working .. Yeah....

http://jsfiddle.net/naveenkumarpg/1000s8y0/16/

Answer (score 2):

```
#navigation > ul > li:hover .hidden, .hidden:hover {
    display: block;
}
```

demo - http://jsfiddle.net/1000s8y0/15/

Answer (score 1):

That is because you are displaying the `.hidden` children list only when `<a>` is hovered upon, according to this rule:

```
#navigation > ul > li > a:hover + .hidden, .hidden:hover {
    display: block;
}
```

This will not work as the `:hover` pseudo-class is lost once your cursor leaves the element and crosses over into the adjacent, now displayed, `.hidden` element. To avoid this, you force `.hidden` to be shown as long as the parent element, `<li>` is hovered upon. Therefore, we can use this selector:

```
#navigation > ul > li:hover .hidden, .hidden:hover {
    display: block;
}
```

See working fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/1000s8y0/14/

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
#navigation li ul {
    display: none;
}
```

Just use this:

```
.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

Making sure the display:none is applied with least specificity so hovering style can override it.

http://jsfiddle.net/1000s8y0/17/